# Error MaxPoolSize on Firebird database

Tags: c#, connection-pooling, firebird

In connection to the database I use a pool of connections and Firebird database. I use FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient version 2.6.5.0.
I have the following connection string:

```
<add name="db" connectionString="Server=***;user   
id=***;password=***;Charset=ANSI_CHARSET;Database=***;
Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=10" 
providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
```

I have the following code that uses the connection to the database:

```
IEnumerable<Orders> ord = new List<Orders>();
using(FbConnection fbCon = new FbConnection("my connection string"))
{
    fbCon.Open();
    using(FbCommand command = fbCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT first 100 ID, SYMBOL, NUMBER, POS FROM Z1";
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Before Close: {0}", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.GetPooledConnectionCount(fbCon)));
        ord= command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection).ConvertToList<Orders>();
    }
}
```

However, I receive error:

```
Timeout exceeded.
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckMaxPoolSize ()
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPool.CheckOut ()
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open ()
```

Error is caused by reaching MaxPoolSize ... every time when I call the above code, in the Output window I ancillary message:

```
Before Close: 1
Before Close: 2
...
Before Close: 10
```

Comment: Have you tried version 4.1.0.0?

Comment: When I used version 4.1.0.0, I got similar error "Connection pool is full".

Comment: You are not disposing your FBCommand, that probably prevents the connection from getting clean-up as well.

Comment: I changed code that disposing FBCommand, but I still have the same error.

Comment: I don't see a loop here so how can you have more than one message in output? Provide a real code.

Comment: The code is real. When invoke it for the fifth time, that is I connect to the database for the fifth time I have a message Before Close: 5, and for the tenth time I have the message Before Close: 10.  It follows that, ultimately, the connection is not disposed, by utilizing the method GetPooledConnectionCount, and therefore I get an error when I connect to the database for the eleventh time

Comment: The code is not real, because for instance the `zam` variable is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may lead to an exception and never reach the Close(), thus leaving the connection open, which could lead to having too many connections open.

You may want to try implementing a Using() in your code.

[Here is an article that describes this in more detail.](http://dotnetweblog.wordpress.com/2008/01/19/max-pool-size-reached/)

I had a similar problem with reaching Max connections and the Using() did help.

Comment: When I implemented a Using() in my code or try, catch with finally, I still have similar error.

Comment: I just lost my hope to find solution. I have similar situation. I restarting app every 15, but i will try using FbConnection.ClearAllPools() on pool exception

Answer (score 0):

Try using recycling your connection pool in iis. You can set it to reset every 60 minutes or so. This would certainly fix your issue.